# Is Amazon EC2 really inexpensive? How does "on demand" works?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I see the smallest and the cheapest price for Amazon EC2 is 0.080 per hour which gives us 0.080*24*31= $60 per month -- the price of cheapest dedicated physical server.

So, what is the essence? May be they count only for access time or something?

Comment: It's up to you to close the instances you don't need, or you'll get billed as long as you keep them online.

Comment: So this means no benefits from virtuality.

Comment: If you really need 24/7/365, you should use their "Heavy Utilization Reserved Instances". There is an upfront charge, and a reduced per-hour cost, which comes down to significantly less than "On Demand" would cost running for a whole year.

Comment: I don't understand what does "reserved" mean. In all cases they will bill me while instance is running and won't if not.

Comment: http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/reserved-instances/

Comment: @Sven I have read this. For me this just means that with "on demand" service they can reject turning it on.

Comment: @SuzanCioc No, they will not reject your request to provision an "on demand" instance. You are thinking of a "spot" instance.

Comment: SO what is the difference between "on demand" and "reserved" instances? What I get paying for "reservation"?

Comment: Reserved instances = you pay a 1- or 3-year up-front "reservation" fee. In exchange, you get a much lower hourly usage rate. All of this is well documented on their pricing pages...

Comment: So, the only difference between "on demand" and "reserved" is payment scheme?

Comment: Yes. In fact, if you buy a reserved instance and you already have an instance of the type and in the availability zone you made a reservation for, it becomes one instantly and automatically. It's just a billing change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the smallest and cheapest price for Amazon EC2 is $0.020/hour, for the t1.micro instances.

You only pay when the server is turned on. If you don't need the servers at night, you can turn them on and pay $0.000/hour (*yes, nothing, except for storage costs*) for that time.

This can be very handy for some use cases - as an example, some people might only need two small servers during the evening, but 10 hefty servers during the day.

Things get significantly cheaper when you purchase reserved instances, as well.

Comment: Sorry but it looks useless. Nobody will turn off his/her site at night. This looks like just a marketing trick.

Comment: Am I correct thinking I need to go to the command line and issue `shutdown` command manually to stop billing?

Comment: @SuzanCioc On the contrary. I have a distributed application that does do dynamic scaling. The web front-ends never go down, but the processing nodes come and go. When we stop the processing instances, we don't get billed for when they're offline.

Comment: Yes but if we are speaking about cheapest option (i.e. only one light frontend), we have nothing to turn off.

Comment: I.e. EC2 can help to control expenses in large projects but it is not inexpensive itself.

Comment: @SuzanCioc: The benefit is not the lowest price but the fact that you only pay for what you need. And ~15$/month for the smallest option isn't exactly expensive.

Comment: `You only pay for what you need` looks like just a slogan. It can't be organized while creating small web site, because what I need is just web page operational all the time, which is not cheap.

Comment: @SuzanCioc: Then look elsewhere. They don't claim it's a service for everyone and they don't claim to be the cheapest. And if you think that 15$/month is expensive, you better start looking for another hobby.

Comment: They wrote it as "inexpensive" on their page. I just want to understand what they meant. What is expensive for me myself does not matter, I am just comparing offers.

Comment: @SuzanCioc - "Expensive" and "Inexpensive" are completely subjective terms. I'm building a system similar to what sysadmin1138 has, and believe me, it is **very** inexpensive for us to use EC2 versus having to purchase physical servers to handle a very bursty load. Like others have said, perhaps EC2 isn't for you.

Answer (score 2):

It's certainly less expensive than keeping a pool of servers on (even with standby power management).  The whole point of the cloud (regardless of vendor) is not to somehow claim that spinning up a cloud based server is going to be cheaper than spinning up a single dedicated server - but rather that the entire operational cost (power, cooling, space, admins) will be cheaper and on top of that you have access to almost infinite capacity. Keeping that extra capacity is WAY cheaper for the cloud than any individual company (thus the inexpensive bit.  However AWS is still the wrogn model for the most inexpensive way to scale

PAAS (Amazon Beanstalk, Google app engine, Microsoft Azure), is a far more efficient way of scaling applications.  In that model applications can scal as needed and deprovision on the fly.  In IAAS you the user has to somehow manage the number of instances.  In the Paas scenario your bill is simply how many resources you've used - without the need to manage any instances.